# Type of update jpa entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3, I have to update a complex entity

with many one to many, one to one and nested relation...

is it a better pratice to pass by many update directly by query.. or pass by entity object?

Answer (score 0):

The most peformant way to do the update might be a native query, or possibly a written JPQL query.  However, from a practically point of view, you might choose to do this by updating the fields in the respective Java entities and then persisting them.  One of the main points of using Hibernate/JPA is to be able to interact with your database from your Java layer, rather than using SQL queries.  Which option you choose depends on your exact goals or requirements.

Comment: only downside of a update query  is the method will have a lot of parameter